# Automatically insert email signature into Outlook Meeting Invite

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-addin

I have been searching the web for a way to do this but no such luck. My goal is to save a meeting agenda template into an email signature which would be inserted into every meeting invite created by me.

Looking for some clues on how to do this?

Comment: What version of Outlook?  I think you need to do it the other way around.  Create a custom meeting template that includes the desired signature.  Then create a new meeting based on your custom template.

Comment: I got Microsoft Outlook 2010. But others in the company got 2013.

Comment: Outlook 2010 on include the form designer so you're good.  File -> Options -> Customize Ribbon, then, in the Right Side pane, click to turn on the Developer Tab.  From there you can design Meeting Request template to your specification.  Then, to use it, you will select New -> Meeting Request Using -> (Your Custom Template) from the Outlook Home tab.  Let me know if this works for you and I'll make an answer out of it.

Comment: this works too! you probably should submit this as an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Outlook 2010 and newer include the form designer.

File -> Options -> Customize Ribbon, then, in the Right Side pane, click to turn on the Developer Tab.

From there you can design Meeting Request template to your specification.

Then, to use it, you will select:

New -> Meeting Request Using -> (Your Custom Template) from the Outlook Home tab.

Comment: Here's what I had to: In Outlook 2013, go to Developer tab > Design a Form > select Meeting Request <Hidden>. Then pasted my signature from my emails into the meeting request. Clicking Save only saved it as an actual meeting request on the calendar. The trick was to Publish it with a name. Then I could select it from Calendar > New Items > Custom Forms > <my form>

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the [ItemSend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865076(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Application class where you can check out the message class of the outcoming Outlook item and change the message body if required.

Think you will find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) article helpful.

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look at this helpful guide too!